# Why pass "this" to Thread constructor?

Tags: java, multithreading

"this" is used to refer to the members of the current class. I was trying a program in java using multithreading.

this => object of the current class where it is referred

The program is

```
class Thread_child implements Runnable{
    Thread t;

    Thread_child()
    {
        t = new Thread(this,"DemoThread");
        System.out.println("ChildThread:"+t);
        t.start();
    }
    public void run(){
    char a[] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'};
    try{
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println("ChildThread:"+i+"\t char :"+a[i]);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
     }
     catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("ChildThread Interrupted");
     }
      System.out.println("Exiting from the Child Thread!");
    }
}
class Thread_eg{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Thread_child();
        try{
            for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            System.out.println("MainThread:"+i);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("MainThread Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting from the Main Thread!");

    }

}
```

What does this Thread() constructor do . why do we need to pass 'this' as a parameter to it. I tried to run it without giving the parameter but the child threads were not run.only the mainthread was printed . when i replaced the thread constructor with the parameter it ran the child threads. why is that so?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: It hasn't changed, but I have linked 6

Comment: As a completely separate issue, please use consistent indentation and formatting, as it will make your code a *lot* more readable by humans.  Having two close curly braces directly below each other is a bad sign, and in `Thread_eg` it looks to me like the `main` method is being terminated halfway down.

Comment: BTW: You can replace `a[i]` with `(char)('A' + i)`

Comment: FYI passing `this` to another thread from the constructor is not thread safe as your object isn't fully initialized. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String%29) for that constructor, and all should become clear.  Pay particular attention to the part that states

> If the `target` argument is not `null`, the `run` method of the `target` is called when this thread is started. If the target argument is `null`, this thread's `run` method is called when this thread is started.

(The underlying issue is that a Thread is *just* a thread, and doesn't inherently do anything.  You need to tell it what to execute.)

Comment: It can be clarified: "this thread's run method is called" should be read as "this *Thread object's* run method"; in this case the `run` desired to be used is the one from the `Thread_child` *object* and not the new `Thread` *object* (which will do nothing by default). An alternative is to subclass Thread and override the run in there to make it do something. (The Thread object *is more than/not just a thread*, as it the *object* which represents/manages/abstracts a thread.)

Comment: @pst the latter part is true - it is an abstraction of the Thread at the Java level, of course.  What I wanted to get across was that a `java.lang.Thread` will not actually execute anything - you either need to pass it a `Runnable` or subclass it to override `run()`.  That's what I was trying to get across - and in that context, if you change the constructor so it's no longer supplying a `Runnable`, is it really surprising that that Runnable is no longer run? :)

Comment: I agree with this answer, just a few nits. :) The documentation could also use some better wording... but maybe that's me.

Answer (score 3):

Because `this` is the `Runnable` object (`Thread_child`) whose `run()` method gets called.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of implementing a Thread. One is create a class that `extends Thread` class and this class runs as a thread in VM.

```
MyThread mt = new MyThread();
mt.start();
```

The start will result in execution of `run` method that was overridden from `Thread`.

In case you could not extend to `Thread`, you can implement `Runnable` which makes you implement `run` method. Now to run this class you need to pass an object of it to `Thread`.

```
MyRunnable mr = new MyRunnable();
Thread t = new Thread(mr); // telling the thread what needs to be execute through run method
t.start();
```

In your code since you are starting thread in constructor, you have passed `this` instead my `mr` in above example. Basically you need to tell `Thread` what it needs to do via `run` method.

This is how `run` of Thread looks like:

```
public void run() {
if (target != null) { //target is nothing but a Runnable.
    target.run(); 
}
}
```